# Check and/or set button state mvc php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to php/mvc and experimenting with a small website.

I would like to change to state of a button depending on a select query. It's a simple '*favourite*' toggle button. The query will look to the '`favourite`' table of my db for the '`isFav`' field (0 or 1).

I would like the button colour to be **green** (btn-success) if the query finds a result (1), and the colour to be **default** (btn-default) if not (0).

Should be simply but I can't seem to get it. I think I am getting confused regarding passing of the variables between my view and model.

My **books_model.php** code is as follows

```
class BooksModel
{

    public function isFav()
        {
            $book_id = $_GET['id']; // from url
            $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            $sql = "SELECT isFav FROM favourite WHERE book_id = :book_id AND user_id = :user_id AND isFav = 1";
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(':book_id', $book_id);
            $query->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
            $query->execute();

            if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
                    $css = 'btn-success';
                    echo $css; //for testing
                } else {
                    $css = 'btn-default';
                    echo $css; // for testing
                }
        }
}
```

My **books.php** controller is as follows;

```
class Books extends Controller
{

    function itemView()
        {
            $itemView_model = $this->loadModel('Books');
            $this->view->books = $itemView_model->itemView();
            $this->view->render('books/itemView');  
            $itemView_model->isFav();  
        }
}
```

My **itemView.php** html button code is as follows;

```
echo '<button class="btn '.$css.'"></button>';
```

The only thing printed on the page is a btn-success or btn-default (top left). This toggles whenever I click the button. Therefore I assume my query is working.

Apologies for the code I am a newbie and I do appreciate any help offered, even a point in the right direction.

Comment: Hi there, you've tagged this under a ASP.NET MVC tag. Suggest you remove that one as it's not relevant to your post.

Comment: I don't get what's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function isFav() {
    (...)
    if ($query->rowCount() == 1) {
        $css = 'btn-success';
        echo $css; //for testing
    } else {
        $css = 'btn-default';
        echo $css; // for testing
    }
    return $css;
}
```

And in your View:

```
echo "<button class=\"btn ".$itemView_model->isFav()."\"></button>";
```

The reason: Your Variable `$css` in your `isFav()` method is not known in your view (the scope of the variable is the `isFav()` method). 
This line: 
    $itemView_model->isFav(); 
Requests the return value of this function, so, clearly, the value bust be returned in order to be available.

The reason you see the seemingly correct answer printed is that the `echo` call is in the same scope as the `$css` variable.

Comment: thank you very much @Burki it works perfectly. I now know where I was going wrong thanks to your explanation!